# SSH command fails when regenerating certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, docker-machine

I'm trying to regenerate certs for my instance on AWS through Docker-Machine as I do need to do it quite often for some reason. All of the sudden I'm getting this error after running `docker-machine regenerate-certs [instance]`:

```
Error running "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo -E apt-get install -y  curl": ssh command error:
command : DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo -E apt-get install -y  curl
err     : exit status 100
output  : E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Executing `sudo dpkg --configure -a` won't make the problem go away.

Why I'm getting this all of the sudden and how can I troubleshoot it ?

Comment: Sounds you shut down the machine in the middle of an installation or maybe killed `dpkg`. Run the suggested command again and try looking up its error code or posting it here. You may have better luck with this in ServerFault or the Ubuntu one.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many times I run the suggested command. It just executes but the error output remains.